# How can I zoom to a particular location on a map on button click. I am using swift and MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

This is how the button action looks in my view controller.

```
     func mapButtonClickedInScrollview(sender: UIButton) {
         let myWorldViewController = MyWorldViewController(nibName: "MyWorldViewController", bundle: nil)
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myWorldViewController, animated: true)
     }
```

This is how my map looks which is set in another view controller(i.e MyWorldViewController):

```
   [enter link description here][1]
```

So when I click that button, i should go to another controller and it should automatically zoom to that car pin which is shown in the image above.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Nddd.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a navbar, first create a push segue from origin to destination view controller, don't reuse the same VC since you'll need more logic behind it, then give it an identifier, lets say `expandedAnnotation`. Then create a "selectedAnnotation property on your current VC `MyWorldViewController` 
You will need to use MapKit's `didSelectAnnotationView` and find the annotation you selected by, (example on a project I have where my annotations are Artworks (custom class name))

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation as? Artwork {
        selectedAnnotation = annotation
        performSegueWithIdentifier("expandedAnnotation", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Then, in your overriden `prepareForSegue` function, pass the annotation to the destination viewcontroller. Of course first create a property for the annotation in the destination view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "expandedAnnotation") {
        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DestinationViewController
        destinationVC.annotation = selectedAnnotation
    }
```

And thats it, in your destinationVC `viewDidLoad`, add the annotation to the mapView and center its region around it. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am using nib files instead of storyboard, I always have this problem of passing data from one view controller to another and this is where I get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

Pass coordinate of the point of interest to your new view controller and in it's map view use `setRegion`. The code might look like this:

```
var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoordinate, span: 200)
region = mapView.regionThatFits(region)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```